# How can I create the correct path to create images in a gt table

Tags: r, filepath, gt

I want to include images of country flags in a table created by the gt R package

```
library(tibble)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(country = c("Italy","Wales"), 
             flag = c("images/flags/Italy.png","images/flags/Wales.png")
             )

# example with hardcoded country
df %>% 
  gt() %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(vars(flag)),
    fn = function(x) {
      country = "Wales"
      local_image(
        filename = paste0("images/flags/",country,".png")
    )
    }
  )
```

Hardcoding in the country into this code produces an output - but obviously always repeats the same flag irrespective of the value of the country column

So I am looking the correct way to replace "Wales" with some reference to the vars(country) of the same row

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't get your question because you seem to have the path already in your data frame? However, how about the following

```
BASE.PATH <- "images/flags/"
IMG.TYPE <- ".png"


df <- data.frame(
  country = c("Italy","Wales"))


create.path <- function(row) {
  path <- paste(BASE.PATH, row["country"], IMG.TYPE, sep = "")
  return(path)
}

df$image.path <- apply(df, 1, create.path)


load.country.image <- function(row) {
  my.image <- my.load.logic(row["image.path"])
  return(my.image)
}

df$image <- apply(df, 1, load.country.image)
```

This dynamically creates the path for you, and loads the image. You only have to change `load.country.image` according to your needs. My guess is

```
load.country.image <- function(row) {
  country.image <- local_image(filename = row["image.path"])
  return(country.image)
}
```

I hope this helps!

PS: Can you please clarify, if this is not what you are looking? Thank you!

**EDIT**
If you want to use `tibble` and `gt`, the following should work on your computer as it does on mine.

```
library(tibble)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(country = c("Italy","Wales"), 
             flag.path = c("images/flags/Italy.png","images/flags/Wales.png"))


df %>% 
  gt() %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(vars(flag.path)),
    fn = function(flag.path) {
      #  The key is here.
      lapply(flag.path, local_image)
    }
  )
```

The key to the problem is to understand that `text_transform` passes the `locations` column/row as a whole to `fn`. In other words, `flag.path` is just a vector.

Comment: Thanks The latter option works on my computer as well - even though I use Windows!. As you say, the crux of the issue is in the final sentence. I can just use the first part of your code to create the image.path variable and use that instead of flag.path in the gt section. i.e. no need to create and apply a load.country.image function